# joining two select queries results in one row for each value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table called `CharUser` has the following data

```
UserID UserName UserPhone UserAddress
```

also a table called `subscriptionjob`

```
subID userId   companyid
```

another table called user `UsersCvs` has the following data

```
CVId   Companyuserid   cvpath
```

I want to do a query that result as the following for each row

```
userid   username   userphone  useraddress usercv
```

the userid is given from the `subcriptionjob` table
i tried the following
the first query

```
SELECT        CharUserId, CharUserName, CharUserPassword, CharUserMail, CharUserPhone, CharUserAddress, CharUserGender, ProgId, CharUserBirthdate
FROM            CharUser
WHERE        (CharUserId IN
                             (SELECT        CompanyUserId
                                FROM            SubsciptionJob
                                WHERE        (JobId = 1)))
```

and this the second query

```
SELECT        TOP (1) CvPath
FROM            UsersCvs
WHERE        (CompanyUserId IN
                             (SELECT        CompanyUserId
                                FROM            SubsciptionJob AS SubsciptionJob_1
                                WHERE        (JobId = 1)))
ORDER BY CvId DESC
```

Both work alone just fine
i tried to combine them putting union in between but it doesn't work

i want to attach the cvpath column to the first query with a unique value for each row

any ideas.. ?

thank you

Comment: You don't need a union, you need a join between the two result sets.

Comment: Are CompanyUserID and CharUserID the same thing? Why not just call it UserID consistently throughout the model? Prefixing every single column with the table name it's from often has the opposite effect of what's intended - it makes your code *less* self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
SELECT CharUserId
     , CharUserName
     , CharUserPassword
     , CharUserMail
     , CharUserPhone
     , CharUserAddress
     , CharUserGender
     , ProgId
     , CharUserBirthdate
     , (SELECT TOP (1) CvPath
       FROM UsersCvs
       WHERE CompanyUserId IN (SELECT CompanyUserId
                               FROM SubsciptionJob
                               WHERE JobId = 1)
       ORDER BY CvId DESC) AS CvPath    
FROM CharUser
WHERE CharUserId IN (SELECT CompanyUserId
                     FROM  SubsciptionJob
                     WHERE JobId = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more efficient than answer above:

```
SELECT CharUserId, 
       CharUserName, 
       CharUserPassword, 
       CharUserMail, 
       CharUserPhone, 
       CharUserAddress, 
       CharUserGender, 
       ProgId, 
       CharUserBirthdate,
       (SELECT TOP (1) CvPath FROM UsersCvs c where c.CompanyUserID=X.CharUserID
       FROM CharUser X
       WHERE (CharUserId IN 
                           (SELECT CompanyUserId FROM SubsciptionJob 
                            WHERE (JobId = 1)))
```

It may be even more efficient by using an inner join between the subscription table and The CharUser table.

Comment: I guess you wanted to join the SubscriptionJob table and then optimize the performance. I didn't do that in my answer because it wasn't the point there, but in your edit it seems your post forget some 'content', because actually there is something missing so it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT CharUserId, CharUserName, CharUserPassword, CharUserMail, 
    CharUserPhone, CharUserAddress, 
    CharUserGender, ProgId, CharUserBirthdate,cvpath
FROM CharUser CU
JOIN subscriptionjob SJ ON SJ.UserId = CU.UserID
INNER JOIN 
(   SELECT cvpath,Companyuserid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Companyuserid ORDER BY A.CVID DESC) X
    FROM UsersCvs A
)R ON R.X = 1 AND CU.UserID = R.Companyuserid
WHERE JobId = 1
```